# Is it possible to destructure an object in switch operator?

Tags: swift, pattern-matching

Today I found a clumsy piece of code:

```
if segue.identifier == "settings" {
  if let settingsController = segue.destination as? SettingsController 
  {
    //...setup settings controller here
  }
} else if segue.identifier == "mocks" {
  if let mocksController = segue.destination as? MocksController 
  {
    //...setup mocks controller here controller here
  }
}
//... and a lot of if-elses
```

I really hate to have `if-else-if` in my code and decide to refactor this piece with `switch`. Unfortunately my knowledge of swift patter-matching are very limited, so the best I could do is:

```
switch segue.identifier! {
  case "mocks" where segue.destination is MocksController:
    let mocksController = segue.destination as! MocksController
    // do corresponding staff here
  break

  case "settings" where segue.destination is SettingsController:
    let settingsController = segue.destination as! SettingsController
    // do corresponding staff here
  break
}
```

I'm wondering is it possible to extract `identifier` and `destination` properties from `segue` object using pattern-matching like in pseudo-code below:

```
switch segue {
  case let destination, let identifier where destination is ... && identifier == "...": 
  //do somthing 
  break
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it's currently possible to directly extract property values in a given pattern – you could always just switch over `(segue.identifier, segue.destination)` though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YES, it's totally possible.
Swift is powerful ;)

```
switch (segue.identifier, segue.destination) {
    case let ("mocks"?, mocksController as MocksController):
             // do corresponding stuff here
  ...
}
```